# Can I expose or publish a SOAP web service on Heroku?

Tags: web-services, soap, heroku, salesforce

We have Salesforce in house and need a proxy server to send API calls to an external Web Service interface (Box).  Since Salesforce only allows 10 callouts per apex invocation, we need an external cloud server to send these callouts.  Not having the money for CastIron or even Pervasive, I was wondering if we could implement this on Heroku?

Of course, Heroku needs to be able to receive Soap messages and send them.
If it can, this would be all we need for our Box integration. (I think)

Does Heroku have addons that receive Soap Messages?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, Heroku is designed for, among others, use cases like this.

> Run and scale any type of app.
>
> Run any web or background process with any web framework or worker
>   type. Get direct, granular control over your app's workloads. Scale
>   distributed processes effortlessly with a single command. Easily scale
>   to millions of users.

[Heroku Home Page](http://www.heroku.com)